# Is there an image processing library for C++/CLI that fits my needs: especially: how can I display intensity images on a windows form in real time?

Tags: image, image-processing, c++-cli, real-time

I am working on a Visual C++/CLI "Windows Forms" project that touches image processing. The intensity (grayscale) image values that I have to deal with are short integers aquired at a framerate of ~400fps.

Question 1: Is there an image processing library comparable to CImg that runs with managed c++ that I can use to process the images? Great thing about CImg is: it offers a constructor, that accepts a pointer to the first image value in the memory, the number of image pixels and the byte size of the pixel values. This is exactly what I am looking for, but I did not manage to get CImg.h running using managed C++: I got it to compile, but I seem to be unable to instantiate a CImg object.

Question 2: What would be the best approach to draw images in real time on a Form? My first approach was to generate Bitmaps using the SetPixel() method and draw the Bitmaps using a Graphics object. However, this approach proved to be far from real time capability.

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated!

[edit: I just succeeded in integrating CImg into my C++/CLI project. I can now display the camera output using the CImageDisplay class. However, this can only be a workaround. The Application I'm developing consists of an MDIParent and the camera live view should be run in an MDIChild. I do not see any possibility to realize this using CImg (would be glad to be proven wrong!). Therefor, both questions are still of great importance to me!]

Comment: Few points:
(a) Modern monitors are not capable of displaying image in 400FPS
(b) Human eye is not capable to handle 400FPS as well.

Comment: That's right... I should have added: the display does not need to show every single image. A framerate of 20fps would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL would be a good choice.  You can load the image into a texture, then draw a textured quad (or two triangles) filling your MDI child window.